# How to fix errors with "wheel metadata" and "Rust toolchain" when installing fastapi[all]?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to `pip install fastapi[all]` but I'm getting a "wheel metadata" error. I've tried installing Rust but I'm still getting same error:

[image]

It is something about a Rust cargo manager.

I already installed that, but it still doesn't fix the error about wheel metadata.

My *Scripts* folder also doesn't have an activate or a deactivate batch file. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In the Uvicorn repository [here](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn#quickstart), it says when installing with `[all]`, 'Cython-based' dependencies will be used. Because you are using Windows, 'Cython-based' dependencies are not supported.

Fix this by using `pip install fastapi` instead of `pip install fastapi[all]`. If you need any more dependencies later, such as Jinja2, install them manually.